# Why did the father in the Truman Show appear in the town as a homeless person?

Tags: the-truman-show

In the scene where Truman is going to work and notices the homeless man to be his father, they cart the father off and then make him reappear later in the show on purpose. Why was he dressed as a homeless in the first place?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

He dressed like that to sneak past the rest of the cast. His appearance wasn't part of the in-universe show, but his attempt to write himself back into the show by showing himself to be alive. (And not to derail the show as I originally misremembered.)

Comment: I don't think his goal was to reveal the truth to Truman but to get back into the show for his own benefit. Otherwise they wouldn't use him during the search, no?

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro Damn. I think you're right on that. Been too long since I saw the movie. Doesn't change the core of the answer, but I'll edit to fix this detail.